# prevent the sub windows to open multiple times

Tags: python, wxpython

I am creating an application by using the language wxPython.
I have a simple problem in which I cant really find the solution in the internet.

I have a main user interface with a menubar which contain a menu called new file.
By clicking the new file, a new window will appear demanding the user to fill up the necessary information.

The problem is that, by clicking multiple times the menu (new file), the application opens multiple windows.

How can i prevent this?

Comment: I don't know wxPython, but a simple way to handle that is by using a [Modal Dialog](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/Dialog.html#phoenix-title-modal-and-modeless).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code creates a new sub frame if one doesn't exists already.
If it does exist already, it uses the existing sub frame.

Note the code is tested with latest wxpython phoenix and classic.

```
import wx
from wx.lib import sized_controls


class MultiMessageFrame(sized_controls.SizedFrame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MultiMessageFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        pane = self.GetContentsPane()
        text_ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(
            pane, style=wx.TE_READONLY | wx.TE_CENTRE | wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        text_ctrl.SetSizerProps(proportion=1, expand=True)
        text_ctrl.SetBackgroundColour('White')
        self.text_ctrl = text_ctrl

        pane_btns = sized_controls.SizedPanel(pane)
        pane_btns.SetSizerType('horizontal')
        pane_btns.SetSizerProps(align='center')

        button_ok = wx.Button(pane_btns, wx.ID_OK)
        button_ok.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_button_ok)

    def append_msg(self, title_text, msg_text):
        self.SetTitle(title_text)
        self.text_ctrl.AppendText(msg_text)

    def on_button_ok(self, event):
        self.Close()


class MainFrame(sized_controls.SizedFrame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.SetInitialSize((800, 600))
        self.CreateStatusBar()
        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)
        menu_file = wx.Menu()
        menu_file.Append(
            wx.ID_NEW, 'Show msg', 'Add a new message to message frame')
        menubar.Append(menu_file, '&File')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.on_new, id=wx.ID_NEW)

        self.count = 1
        self.multi_message_frame = None

    def on_new(self, event):
        title_text = 'MultiMessageFrame already exists'

        if not self.multi_message_frame:
            title_text = 'Newly created MultiMessageFrame'
            self.multi_message_frame = MultiMessageFrame(
                self, style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.FRAME_FLOAT_ON_PARENT)
            self.multi_message_frame.Bind(
                wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.on_multi_message_frame_close)
            self.multi_message_frame.Center()
            self.multi_message_frame.Show()

        self.multi_message_frame.append_msg(
            title_text, 'message no.{}\n'.format(self.count))
        self.count += 1

    def on_multi_message_frame_close(self, event):
        self.multi_message_frame = None
        event.Skip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    main_frame = MainFrame(None)
    main_frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Excuse me, when I try to launch your code, python can't import sized_controls. Do you know why pthon can't import this module?

Comment: @maximus - Maybe you are using and old version of wxpython that doesn't have sized_controls. What version are you using, I've now tested the code to be ok with both classic and phoenix.

Comment: ok..anyhow, i managed to solve my problem by using your algorithm. Thanks